# Rock Paper .. game

Tags: c

This code runs just fine.
but there is some minor mistake in the program. I don't know what's the problem 'cause it's like I keep on winning the game and the computer just loses the game every time. 3

the game Rock, Paper, Scissors. My problem is if I execute the program, I just keep winning.I need the game to let the computer win. How can I rectify this?

```
#include <stdio.h
#include <time.h>

int Random(int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d\n", rand() % 3); }

int greater(char ch1, char ch2) {
    if (ch1 == ch2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ((ch1 == 'R') && (ch2 == 's'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((ch2 == 'R') && (ch1 == 's'))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((ch1 == 's') && (ch2 == 'p'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((ch2 == 's') && (ch1 == 'p'))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((ch1 == 'p') && (ch2 == 'r'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((ch2 == 'p') && (ch1 == 'r'))
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char playerchar, computerchar, a;
    int playerscore = 0, compscore = 0, b;
    char ch[] = {'R', 'P', 'S'};
    printf("\n");
    printf("~~~~~Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Game~~~~~\n\n");
    printf("Choose a number\n 1. for Rock\n 2. for Paper\n 3. for Scissiors\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Player's Turn :\n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        getchar();
        playerchar = ch[b - 1];
        printf("You chose %c\n", playerchar);

        printf("Computer's Turn :\n");
        b = Random(3) + 1;
        computerchar = ch[b - 1];
        printf("Computer chose %c\n", computerchar);

        if ((greater(computerchar, playerchar) == 1))
        {
            compscore += 1;
            printf("Computer got it!\n\n");
        }
        else if ((greater(computerchar, playerchar) == -1))
        {
            compscore += 1;
            playerscore += 1;
            printf("It's a draw\n");
        }
        else
        {
            playerscore += 1;
            printf("You got it!\n\n");
        }

        printf("You     : %d\nComputer: %d\n\n",playerscore,compscore);
    }          

    if (compscore > playerscore)
    {
        printf("Computer win the game!\n\n");
    }
    else if (playerscore > compscore)
    {
        printf("You win the game!\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The game is draw\n");
    }

    return 0;}
```

Comment: Welcome. Did you try running your program through a debugger?

Comment: Why do you have `'r'` and `'R'`?

Comment: *"This code runs just fine. but there is some minor mistake in the program."* - Wrong, it does not run fine. It just seems like it does, and there are many major issues.

Comment: "There are many major issues". well that's what I want to know, what are the major issues. "Why do you have 'r' and 'R'?" it is probably a mistake. thanks.

Comment: 1) This code does not even compile. (Missing closing > on first line)

Comment: 2) Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings

Comment: But you really need to learn to debug. Here is some advice https://github.com/klutt/debug-small-c-programs/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no point complex if statements for determining the winner. Just realize that rock paper scissors is basically just a [directed cycle graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Directed_cycle_graph)

```
// Returns winner in rock paper scissors
// 0 - Rock, 1 - Paper, 2 - Scissors 
// Return values:
// 0  - draw
// 1  - a win, b loose
// -1 - b win, a loose
int rps(int a, int b) {
    if(a == b) return 0;
    return (a+1) % 3 == b ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Normal rps (rock, paper, scissors) has 3 nodes in the graph. This can actually easily be generalized to `n` nodes. The algorithm works like this. Start on node `a`. If it's the same as `b`, then it's a draw. Otherwise, check how many steps it is required to to go around the graph to get to `b` and determine the winner depending on if the number of steps is even or odd.

```
int rpsn(int a, int b, int n) {
    if(a == b) return 0;
    int steps = 0;
    while((a+steps) % n != b) steps++;
    return steps % 2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Read about [Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Rock,_Paper,_Scissors,_Lizard,_Spock) for a 5 node version.

I'm fairly confident that the loop could be exchanged for a single clever math operation, but I'm having a brain freeze at the moment. I'll update the post if I find it.

EDIT:

I found a way. Here is a very short rps function with no loops for arbitrary `n`:

```
// Returns the number of steps required to go from a to b 
int steps(int a, int b, int n) { 
    return (n+b-a) % n; 
}

int rpsn(int a, int b, int n) {
    if(a == b) return 0;
    return steps(a,b,n) % 2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

The reason for doing `(n+b-a) % n` instead of `(b-a) % n` is that we need the left operand of `%` to be nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Brother@klutt

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [srand should be called just once at the beginning of the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once). You call it on every call of Random().

But the bigger issue is that your function Random() does not return anything, it just prints the value. This should have grnerated a warning in your compiler. This probably means that Random always returns 0.

To fix the problem, do `return rand() % 3;` instead of printing it.